# How do I install the kernel 3-11.2 on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: installation, 13.04, kernel, backup

I would like to install kernel 3-11.2 on Ubuntu 13.04 (I found this link git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git linux-3.11.y ).
How do I manage to do it ?Also, is it safe to just install a kernel ?Do I have to backup any important files before proceeding ?What does "Kernel Header Files" stand for ?

Answer (score 0):

How to install Kernel 3.11.2 on 32 bit Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Debian, Elementary OS and Pear OS systems:

Download the needed packages:

```
wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.2-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.2-031102_3.11.2-031102.201309262136_all.deb
wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.2-saucy/linux-image-3.11.2-031102-generic_3.11.2-031102.201309262136_i386.deb
wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.2-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.2-031102-generic_3.11.2-031102.201309262136_i386.deb
```

How to install Kernel 3.11.2 on 64 bit Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Debian, Elementary OS and Pear OS systems:

Download the needed packages:

```
wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.2-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.2-031102_3.11.2-031102.201309262136_all.deb
wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.2-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.2-031102-generic_3.11.2-031102.201309262136_amd64.deb
wget -c http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.2-saucy/linux-image-3.11.2-031102-generic_3.11.2-031102.201309262136_amd64.deb
```

Install Kernel 3.11.2:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers*.deb linux-image*.deb
```